# Provide deeper swarm nodes-related metrics

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, metrics, exporter, prometheus-node-exporter

I would like to be able to be able to monitor more accurately the manager nodes within a swarm cluster.
I expect (eg) such a metrics :

```
node_swarm{instance="10.0.0.14:9100",job="node",node_id="123",node_name="node_7",node_availabilty="drain",node_manager_status="Reachable",node_status="unreachable"} 1  
node_swarm{instance="10.0.0.145:9100",job="node",node_id="456",node_name="node_8",node_availabilty="Active",node_manager_status="Unreachable",node_status="down"} 1
```

... if it could also provide the labels of the nodes, these would be the icing on the cake!
...

But for now, I didn't manage to provide such with node_exporter (or cAdvisor)... I may have missed some clue, but they don't sound like they provided such hints.

Do you have any idea on how I could provided such metrics?

I am quite sure I could code them from scratch (or submit a feature request), but I don't want to reinvent the Wheel if it already exists!

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable the [dockerd metrics endpoint and look at one it provides](https://docs.docker.com/config/thirdparty/prometheus/)?

Comment: I didn't know it, but yes I had: they are defined in daemon.json the same way they are in you target link. Unfortunately, I cannot manage to have them work... prometheus keeps saying "connection refused". 
This is a different problem, though. Thanks for the tip, cause I didn't know this existed! I Will try to fix it in order to check this will suit my needs!

Comment: Ok, I had it working. Unfortunately, I don't see how to list node status with them... or not a way I can see at the moment. At least I can see that a node is a manager or not!